# how to set min height with domLayout = 'autoHeight' in ag grid angular

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am wondering if there is a way that the ag-grid can have a min height when using domLayout='autoHeight' ? When there is no rows the filter box cuts out and it doesn't look good because the height of the grid is so short.

Anyone come across this and able to get a min height so the grid is not so short when there are a small amount of records?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there's no such feature in ag-grid.

The easy, but dirty solution:
If rows height is fixed, you can check the amount of rows and based on them choose the 'normal' or 'autoHeight' layout + set grid heigh for 'normal' layout (since it's required)

As a smarter solution (for rows that have different heights and so on):
Once grid is initialized, use smth like that to calculate actual grid's height:

```
let gridHeight = 0;

this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
  const nodeHeight = node.rowHeight;
  gridHeight += nodeHeight;
});
```

Then, comapre the `gridHeigh` with your `minHeight` and set the proper layout and set grid heigh to `minHeight` (only for 'normal' layout)

Notes:

- This solution was originaly designed for similar but different problem - setting up the `normal` layout if grid overflows its parent (so the grid header is fixed and so on), so there might be a better solution that I don't know about;
- In the code above header height is not taken into account;
- It's required to re-calculate proper layout on a bunch of ag-grid hooks like `onGridReady`, `onRowDataChanged`, `onGridSizeChanged`